# Implementing a linked list

Tags: performance, c, linked-list

I am studying data structures at the moment, so I want to see if there is anything wrong with my implementation of linked lists in C, after I checked [Implementing an ArrayList](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/64423/implementing-an-arraylist/64741).

#### Header

```
#ifndef _LINKEDLIST_H
#define _LINKEDLIST_H

#include <stddef.h> /* size_t */
#include <stdbool.h> /* _Bool */
#define _LINKEDLIST_DEFAULT_SIZE (1)

typedef struct _linkedlist _LinkedList;
typedef const unsigned int Index;

#define LinkedList _LinkedList *

LinkedList LinkedList_create();

int LinkedList_add(LinkedList, void *);
int LinkedList_get_val_index(LinkedList, void *);
int LinkedList_get_list_index(LinkedList, const LinkedList *);
int LinkedList_remove(LinkedList, const _Bool, const _Bool);

void LinkedList_set_data(LinkedList, void **, const _Bool, const size_t max);
void LinkedList_clear(LinkedList, const _Bool);
void LinkedList_destroy(LinkedList *, const _Bool);

void *LinkedList_get_value(const LinkedList);

LinkedList LinkedList_get(LinkedList, Index);

LinkedList *LinkedList_get_next(LinkedList);
LinkedList *LinkedList_get_previous(LinkedList);
LinkedList *LinkedList_get_pointer(LinkedList *, Index);

inline size_t LinkedList_get_size_of(const LinkedList);
inline size_t LinkedList_get_size(const LinkedList);

#endif /* _LINKEDLIST_H */
```

#### Source

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "LinkedList.h"

#define VALID_LINKEDLIST_CODE (245)
#define _LinkedList_check(l) \
    if ((l) == NULL || (l)->_Valid != VALID_LINKEDLIST_CODE) \
        abort();

struct _linkedlist {
    size_t depth;
    int _Valid;
    void * value;
    struct _linkedlist *next;
    struct _linkedlist *previous;
};

struct _linkedlist *LinkedList_create(void * initial_value)
{ /* Allocate Memory */
    struct _linkedlist *list = malloc(sizeof(struct _linkedlist));

    if(list == NULL)
        return NULL;

    list->depth = 1;
    list->next = NULL;
    list->previous = NULL;
    list->value = initial_value;
    list->_Valid = VALID_LINKEDLIST_CODE;
    return list;
}

void LinkedList_set_data(struct _linkedlist * list, void ** data, const _Bool freeval, const size_t max)
{ /* Sets the internal array of the arraylist */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    int length;
    for(length = 0; data[length]; ++length);
    if (length < max || max == 0)
        abort();
    LinkedList_clear(list, freeval);
    list->value = data[0];
    for(unsigned int i = 1; i < max; ++i)
        LinkedList_add(list, data[i]);
    list->depth = max;
}

int LinkedList_add(struct _linkedlist *list, void *elem)
{ /* Adds one linked list to the chain with elem as value */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    ++list->depth;
    struct _linkedlist ** l;
    for(l = &list->next; ( *l != NULL ); l = &(*l)->next)
        ++(*l)->depth;
    (*l) = LinkedList_create(elem);
    (*l)->previous = *l;
    return ((*l)->next == NULL);
}

struct _linkedlist *LinkedList_get(struct _linkedlist *list, const unsigned int index)
{ /* Gets the index'th linked list in the chain */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    if (index >= list->depth)
        return NULL;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < index; list = list->next, i++);
    return list;
}

struct _linkedlist **LinkedList_get_pointer(struct _linkedlist ** list, const unsigned int index)
{ /* Gets the index'th linked list in the chain as a pointer */
    _LinkedList_check(*list);
    if (index >= (*list)->depth)
        return NULL;
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < index; list = &(*list)->next);
    return list;
}

inline size_t LinkedList_get_size_of(const struct _linkedlist *list)
{ /* Returns the size of the chain of lists in memory */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    return (sizeof(struct _linkedlist) * list->depth);
}

inline size_t LinkedList_get_size(const struct _linkedlist *list)
{ /* Returns the number of elements in the arraylist */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    return list->depth;
}

int LinkedList_remove(struct _linkedlist * list, const _Bool index, const _Bool freeval)
{ /* Removes one element at a chain index */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    if (index >= list->depth)
        return 2;

    LinkedList_clear(LinkedList_get(list, index), freeval);
    --list->depth;
    return 0;
}

void LinkedList_clear(struct _linkedlist * list, const _Bool freeval)
{ /* Clears the list chain */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    struct _linkedlist * l, * n;
    for( l = list->next; l; l = n) {
        if (freeval)
            free(l->value);
        n = l->next;
        free(l);
    }
    list->next = NULL;
}

void LinkedList_destroy(struct _linkedlist ** list, const _Bool freeval)
{ /* De-allocates the list and its chains from memory
    No usage of list is allowed after this function call */
    _LinkedList_check(*list);
    LinkedList_clear(*list, freeval);
    free(*list);
    *list = NULL;
}

int LinkedList_get_val_index(struct _linkedlist *list, void *elem)
{ /* Looks for elem in list and returns the index or -1 if not found */
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < list->depth; ++i)
        if (elem == (LinkedList_get(list, i)->value))
            return i;
    return -1;
}

int LinkedList_get_list_index(struct _linkedlist *list, const struct _linkedlist ** elem)
{
    _LinkedList_check(list);
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < list->depth; ++i)
        if (*elem == LinkedList_get(list, i))
            return i;
    return -1;
}

void *LinkedList_get_value(const struct _linkedlist *list)
{ /* Return the list's essence, the value */
    return list->value;
}

struct _linkedlist **LinkedList_get_next(struct _linkedlist *list)
{ /* Return the next list in the chain */
    return &list->next;
}

struct _linkedlist **LinkedList_get_previous(struct _linkedlist *list)
{ /* Return the previous line in the chain */
    return &list->previous;
}
```

After checking with valgrind, I see that I have no memory leaks, no read/write errors and no functional or logical errors (after testing).

I want to know if there are any usability or performance problems in the code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your list is a little unusual in that it contains a `depth` field and a
validity check field in each list node.  I've never see this and think that
the depth in particular is a mistake. Your function must traverse the whole
list adjusting the `depth` fields of each item whenever and item is added.
Equally when deleting items you must traverse the remaining items. This means
that the list gets slower as it expands.  This is not a good design.

I think it would be better to remove `depth` from each node and perhaps make
the list head a different structure that holds a pointer to the end of the
list.

Some other observations:

- Your `linkedlist_check` macro should be uppercase and should use a `do {...}
  while(0)` and not end in a semi-colon.
- Avoid using a leading underscore. It's use is reserved. And it adds nothing
  to your code.
- It is often thought best to enclose single-line conditional statements or
  loops in braces:

  ```
  if (length < max || max == 0) {
      abort();
  }
  ```

  There is no universal agreement on this, but it does help to prevent a
  class of errors that can occur if the braces are omitted.  Also empty
  loops are often thought better if coded thus:

  ```
  for(length = 0; data[length]; ++length) {
      /* nothing */
  }
  ```
- In `LinkedList_set_data` the first for-loop seems to search the data array
  for NULL pointers.  If it doesn't find one it will repeat indefinitiely (on
  into undefined memory).  I don't know why this function would ever be
  necessary.
- `LinkedList_add` does not test for failure in calls to `LinkedList_create`.
  The function is also written with double pointers, which is ugly and
  unnecessary.
- I don't see the point of having both `LinkedList_get` and
  `LinkedList_get_pointer`.  Also the latter doesn't increment `i`.
- I see no use in `LinkedList_get_size_of`.  Why would a caller want to know
  the amount of memory occupied by the non-contiguous (opaque) nodes?  Returning the
  number of nodes might have more use (`LinkedList_get_size`).
- `LinkedList_remove` is supposed to remove just one node but 'clears' the
  list after that node.  And it seems to change the depth counter of the head
  of the list but not of other nodes.

... I went no further.